# iOS - Autolayout Constraint Errors for Dynamic UITableViewCell Class

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, height

I have a `UITableViewController` that will display a variety of custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses. Some of these classes have dynamic content that may change the size of the cell.

Some of this dynamic content is generated through `asynchronous operations`, such as downloading images, data, etc. Then the results are used to determine the correct size for the cell.

I am getting a lot of constraint warnings when the cell updates its layout. It appears to break some of the `UITableView` constraints *(i.e. The cell's height was 100 before the data finished downloading, then was updated to 250)*.

The only way I found to fix these warnings, was to add a `delegate` method to the cell's class that is triggered in the `UITableViewController` and call's `[tableView reloadData]`;

This is problematic though, as it ends up re-triggering some of the cell's asynchronous operations, etc.

**My question is, what is the best approach when you have custom `UITableViewCell` class that has dynamic content that changes the cell's size after the table initially loads and displays the cell?**

**Sample Cell Layout:**

- UILabel
- UIImage
- UICollectionView *This is only shown if objects are found for current user. It may display between 1-3 rows of the object's data (thus changing the height of the cell), or will be hidden if no object's found for user.*
- UIButton

**Here's a sample warning:**

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469f2c0 V:|-(5)-[UIView:0x109431f90]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10943fcd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469f590 V:[UIView:0x109431f90]-(5)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10943fcd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174699a00 V:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x102d0b8f0'Welcome!']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x109431f90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174699e10 UILabel:0x102d0b8f0'Welcome!'.height == 32   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469fcc0 V:[UILabel:0x102d0b8f0'Welcome!']-(0)-[UIView:0x102d019c0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469f770 UIView:0x102d019c0.height == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469f9a0 V:[UIView:0x102d019c0]-(0)-[UIImageView:0x102da1cb0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469fb30 UIImageView:0x102da1cb0.height == 161   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17469f810 V:[UIImageView:0x102da1cb0]-(16)-[UILabel:0x102d14150'Optional Message']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174690ef0 V:[UILabel:0x102d14150'Message']-(16)-[UICollectionView:0x103a01a00]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174880230 V:[UICollectionView:0x103a01a00]-(16)-[UIButton:0x102d7e6a0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1748801e0 UIButton:0x102d7e6a0.height == 36   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174883890 V:[UIButton:0x102d7e6a0]-(24)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x109431f90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174882850 UICollectionView:0x103a01a00.height == 220   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174882e40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x10943fcd0.height == 329   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174882850 UICollectionView:0x103a01a00.height == 220   (active)>
```

Comment: Have you tried `[tableView setNeedsLayout]` and `[tableView layoutConstraints]` in the completion block of your async operations?

Comment: Yes, I still got the warnings. See below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is some sort of bug when it comes to using UIButton inside of a UITableViewCell.

Changing the constraint's priority on the UIButton's vertical spacing fixes the error:

**Was:**

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label(32)]-[imageView(100)]-16-[button(buttonHeight)]**-8-**|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:metrics views:views]];

**Now:**

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label(32)]-[imageView(100)]-16-[button(buttonHeight)]**-8@999-**|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:metrics views:views]];

Answer (score 0):

You must set

```
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = tableview.rowHeight 
tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension()
```

After that, everything is about constraints

Comment: .. for example if you have an image, set SizeToFit and margin constraints

Comment: Sorry, I actually already have the tableView rowHeight and estimatedRowHeight set properly. The problem is more that the table loads the cells, the cells start out with one height (lets just say 100), then the async operation finishes and resizes the cell from it's own class to a larger height (varies), then the tableView generates a warning due to constraint errors.